# Differences between setIcon for one JLabel vs an array of JLabels

Tags: java, arrays, icons, jlabel

I'm trying to design a very simple graphic interface where I will be adding some images to using a JLabel loaded with an Icon:

```
JFrame Table = new JFrame("Transporter Room");
Table.setSize(600, 600);
Table.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
Table.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Table.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 20, 20));
```

My problem is loading the icons for an array of JLabels... Something like this works:

```
JLabel playingCard = new JLabel(CardGUI.getIcon(myCard));
JLabel playingCard2 = new JLabel(CardGUI.getIcon(myCard2));
Table.add(playingCard);
Table.add(playingCard2);
```

Just a note, the `CardGUI.getIcon(ob)` is just a static method that sets up the directory correctly and loads up an Icon with a given card object.

Something like this also works (although the *icon is not centered in the layout.. why?)*:

```
JLabel playingCard = new JLabel();
JLabel playingCard2 = new JLabel();
playingCard.setIcon(CardGUI.getIcon(myCard));
playingCard2.setIcon(CardGUI.getIcon(myCard));
Table.add(playingCard);
Table.add(playingCard2);
```

Using arrays of JLabel also works as long as I don't use `setIcon()` but dup my code to declare twice:

```
JLabel[] myLabel = new JLabel[2];
myLabel[0] = new JLabel(CardGUI.getIcon(myCard));
myLabel[1] = new JLabel(CardGUI.getIcon(myCard2));
Table.add(myLabel[0]);
Table.add(myLabel[1]);
```

However, the problem arises when I try to do this (and I need to do this per spec):

```
JLabel[] myLabel = new JLabel[2];
myLabel[0].setIcon(CardGUI.getIcon(myCard));
myLabel[1].setIcon(CardGUI.getIcon(myCard2));
Table.add(myLabel[0]);
Table.add(myLabel[1]);
```

I get a `Execption in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`. I have no idea why. I'm pretty sure the directory to the image is perfectly fine (that's taken care of by another class). Why does this only come up if a JLabel within an array is attempted to be set up?

This is an assignment I'm working on, and I prefer not using any new code that might be potentially be longer as a work around. It should be rather straightforward, if I can get pass this point, I literally use a for loop to load up Icons to JLabels, then another for loop to load up all the JLabels onto a table top (that's another Class I have already set up). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Okay I just realized something rereading my post. Do I need to declare each element of an array individually as well even though I've set them as an array of that type of object? Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes. As my answer said, the elements inside the array are still `null` when you create the array. The second to last bit of code is likely the best you can do without putting `myCard`,`myCard2`, etc. into an array and looping over them.

Comment: Yes, the default value for an Object is `null`, see @user3580294 answer. When you do `String[] arr  = new String[10];` the array holds 10 `null` references.

Comment: *"icon is not centered in the layout.. why?"* The default horizontal alignment for a label is `LEFT`, you can change it to be `CENTER`

Comment: Thanks everyone! Wow, I can't believe I overlooked something so simple. Guess I'm too used to dealing with primitives and taking advantage of the String = shortcut. Many thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a `JLabel[]`, you're creating *the array* of labels. NOT the labels *inside* the array. In other words, the array elements are still `null` after you create the array. That's why your second to last bit of code works, but your last didn't -- in the last bit of code, you didn't initialize the elements in the array, so when you try to call a method on them, you get a `NullPointerException`.